# Contents of mail in google apps

Tags: c#

I am saving emails of a pst file as eml.Then i am opening the file having the eml and then saving it in a  string i.e msg.In the content of msg i am getting small boxes wherever there is a space.please help me resolve this problem.I am using the following code

byte[] bytes = File.ReadAllBytes(EmlPath);
String msg = System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("utf-8").GetString(bytes);

Regards
Sanchaita Chakraborty

Answer (score 0):

Can you check what kind of char is in the msg String where you see the small boxes? if it's an encoding issue as it seem to be, you could replace that chars with a space.

Comment: @Sanchaita that dosent help...Are you saying that whitespaces are converted to that small boxes in your string...